# How to use LIMIT for an update query in hibernate?

Tags: mysql, hibernate, hql, limit

```
UPDATE  tablename SET  col1 = :col1value WHERE id.col2=:col2 Value 
ORDER BY col3 ASC LIMIT 2;
```

I need an alternative for the above query, as LIMIT keyword is not accepted in HQL. `setMaxResults` works only for select query.

Idea is, for the query to update all the records corresponding to `col1value` but one.(`LIMIT` value can be calculated and is available)

Answer (score 0):

limit cannot be used in `HQL` and `query.setMaxResults()` doesnt work with `UPDATE`.

**Alternatively you can follow below approach:**

Write two separate HQL queries where the results of the first query is fed into second query which does the update something lik below

1.first query on IDs only  having limited result set (as per you limit set- `setMaxResults()`).

3.Second query would update based on results of first query `WHERE id IN (result of first query)`